# BackOffInterruptedException thrown during api call with spring retry

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-retry

```
Exception class signifiying that an attempt to back off using a BackOffPolicy was interrupted, most likely by an java.lang.InterruptedException during a call to java.lang.Thread.sleep(long).
```

Above exception thrown during external api call in my code , i annotated the method with below

```
@Retryable(maxAttempts = 10, value = {
        SpringRetryingException.class}, backoff = @Backoff(delay = 10000L, multiplier = 2.0D))
```

i think during sleep some thread interrupted this thread , how to handle this issue ? can we catch this exception in method where am calling the api and throw SpringRetryingException in that catch block , so that it will retry again .

can anyone suggest on this .

Answer (score 0):

You need to find out what interrupted your thread and why.

There is nothing retry can do to help you; if you catch the exception you would have to call the method again. However, it is generally not a good idea to ignore interrupts.